# Como eu consigo trazer em um select um range de datas de um período no banco de dados oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com um dúvida mas queria saber se é possível fazer tal ação.

Eu tenho uma tabela com dois campos de data, data de início e data de fim, eu queria saber se tem como trazer em um select sem o loop e sem bloco, os dias que estão dentro desse range?

No caso eu me refiro as datas exatas e não a quantidade de dias entre as datas.

Eu pensei em criar situações com unions, mas pelo que eu fui vendo no início da query eu já percebi que seria inviável.

```
SELECT START_DATE
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY
WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('28-OCT-01', 'DD-MM-YY')
UNION ALL
SELECT START_DATE + 1
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY
WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('28-OCT-01', 'DD-MM-YY');
```

```
SELECT * FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('28-OCT-01', 'DD-MM-YY');
```

Usei uma base do oracle 11g para fazer o teste, HR.JOB_HISTORY, filtrando o registro do dia 28/10/2001. Para esse registro a data de início é 28/10/2001 e data de fim é 15/03/2005.

Depois pensei em criar um with com a query abaixo.

```
with
dias as
(
SELECT CASE WHEN START_DATE > END_DATE THEN TRUNC(START_DATE - END_DATE)
            WHEN END_DATE > START_DATE THEN TRUNC(END_DATE - START_DATE)
            END AS QTD_DIAS,
            START_DATE,
            END_DATE,
       A.* 
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY A
);
```

E levar para uma segunda query o valor da quantidade de dias, que seria a referência do limite de registros que deveria vir no select, limitando através do ROWNUM.

```
SELECT * 
FROM HR.JOB_HISTORY 
WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('28-OCT-01', 'DD-MM-YY')
      AND ROWNUM <= DIAS.QTD_DIAS;
```

Mas também não seria viável porque traria apenas o registro que cair na condição do where.

A propósito, pensando aqui percebi que talvez não exista como conseguir chegar a o resultado sem o loop e sem o bloco pl sql, pelo bloco com o loop não cheguei a fazer mas acredito que dê certo, minha dúvida é mais se apenas com o pl é possível. Caso exista alguma solução será de grande ajuda.

Comment: Luiz, você já tentou alguma coisa? Coloque na pergunta.

Comment: Fiz sim Rodrigo, vou passar as queries mais evidenciadas numa nova resposta pois nos comentários o limite de caracteres é excedido.

Comment: Ok Felipe, Edite a pergunta e insere nela.

Comment: Rodrigo, ajustei a pergunta com as queries.

Comment: Troque TO_DATE('28-OCT-01', 'DD-MM-YY') por TO_DATE('28-10-2001', 'DD-MM-YYYY') antes de mais nada.